# Django templates check whether key is existing

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Urgently needed solution

I have dictionary say

```
dictcontents = {"product1":{"subproduct1":["value1","value2"]},"product2":{"subproduct2":["value3","value4"]}}
```

I have sent dictcontents to template .I want to iterate the dictionary in template and check the key existence `dictcontents["product1"]["subproduct1"]` and get the value of that checked key

where "subproduct1" key is intialised value by user. I need to access the information whether the user has entered the "subproduct1" value or not manually?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
{% for key, val in d.items %}
    {% if val.subproduct1 %}
        {% for value in val.subproduct1 %}
            {{ value }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if val.subproduct2 %}
        {% for value in val.subproduct2 %}
            {{ value }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

or this:

```
{% for key, val in d.items %}
    {% for key2, val2 in val.items %}
        {% if val2 %}
            {% for value in val2 %}
                {{ value }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Aamir .I have edited question.Here the "subproduct1" is a intialised by user.He may add or not that his choices .I want to find wether he has added or not if added i want to fetch the value

Comment: Don't you think `{% if val.subproduct1 %}` does the same thing in my code?

Comment: Updated my answer in which `subproduct1` and `subproduct2` are not hardcoded.